# codeigniter success insert to database but failed to insert uploaded file

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new here, so nice to meet you all.

I have trouble with codeigniter.

Maybe hard to tell so I will show all of my code :

my controller :

```
 function upload_barang(){

    $this->admin_model->login();

    $this->admin_model->valid_product();

    $config['upload_path'] = './produk/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '400';
    $config['max_height']  = '400';

    $this->load->library('upload',$config); 

    $data['query'] = $this->db->get('kategori');

     if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE && ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {

     $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

     $data['success'] = '';

     $this->load->view('backoffice/tambahbarang',$data);

     } else {

       $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

      $data['error'] = '';

      $data = array(
      'idkategori' => $this->input->post('idkategori'),
      'namabarang' => $this->input->post('nbarang'),
      'image' =>  $upload_data['file_name'],
      'status' => 1
   );

    $data_insert = $this->db->insert('barang',$data);

    if($data_insert == TRUE) {

      $data['query'] = $this->db->get('kategori');

      $query = $this->db->get('barang');

      $rows = $query->row();

      $data['idbarang'] = $rows->idbarang; 

      $harga = array(
      'idbarang' => $data['idbarang'],
      'satuan' => $this->input->post('stcbarang'),
      'harga' => $this->input->post('hbarang')
   );

   $this->db->insert('hargabarang',$harga);

   $data['success'] = '<b>Barang Telah Ditambahkan</b>';

    $this->load->view('backoffice/tambahbarang',$data);  

   } else {

    $data['success'] = '<b>Barang Gagal Ditambahkan</b>';

    $this->load->view('backoffice/tambahbarang',$data);  

    }

  }  
}
```

This code success insert all of data to database, except on column 'image' that I fill with '$upload_data['file_name']' this empty on my database.

what's wrong with my code?

please help thanks

Comment: Why you write query in `controller` this is bad use of `MVC`

Comment: Try with removing this line in your code `$data['error'] = '';`

Comment: that just only for test, after successful I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format:

```
    /*
     * ------- Start Image Upload---------
     */
    $config['upload_path'] = 'image/product_images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '400';
    $config['max_height']  = '400';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $error='';
    $fdata=array();
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('product_image'))
    {
            $error =  $this->upload->display_errors();
            echo $error;
            exit();
    }
    else
    {
            $fdata = $this->upload->data();
            $data['product_image']=$config['upload_path'] .$fdata['file_name'];
    }

    /*
     * --------End Image Upload---------
     */
    $this->super_admin_model->save_product_info($data);
```

Comment: Hmm thanks for answer but how about form_validation? if I use this code is only for upload image and then save them into database, How about form validation? how to combine them using form validation?